# Having trouble with integrating facebook authentication

Tags: facebook

I'm following: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

My website has its own login system (which is written in Django/Python). Without using django-social-auth kind of plugin, i want to integrate facebook authentication to my web app.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{{facebook_app_id}}', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//{{host_name}}/external/fb_channel', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    // Additional initialization code here
  };
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

However, i've followed the instruction (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) and the login button shows as expected and when clicked, popup windows shows to allow my application. (I'm running my server at 127.0.0.1 which is localhost)

So, what's next? When user clicks to login and allow it, I was expecting to do some server side validation to log my user in with fb account. But I'm not sure what to do now.

After clicking to login with FB, it flickers and does not hit my server. Need some guidance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't walk you through every bit of code that you'll need, however I can explain the general process that I've used in the past (including with a few Django sites) and hopefully you'll be able to use that to build your site:

1. Integrate the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
2. Bind a JavaScript function which calls [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to a "login with Facebook" button, requesting all the permissions that you need for that user
3. In the `function(response)` section of the `FB.login` call, handle the returned response, then do an Ajax POST to a Django view (I use jQuery for this) which takes the response, parses it to retrieve the access token for the user and store it in the user profile object for that user.
4. You can then use this access_token to make Facebook [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) requests on behalf of that user server-side, or if you want, you can actually just use the JavaScript SDK to make all your calls entirely on the client-side with lots of Ajax to interact with the Django backend.